# How to change min insync replica for multiple topics at once using kafka-config.sh (or any other kafka cli script)

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to change the min insync replica property for multiple kafka topics.
For individual topics, I know we can use this:

```
kafka-configs --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name <topic name> --add-config min.insync.replicas=2 --zookeeper <zookeeper node:port>
```

How do I pass multiple entity names to this command? Or is there any other way to do it via shell, or will I have to write a custom script to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command doesn't accept mutiple topics. You'll need to use bash, awk, or other language you're familiar with

Comment: Can we do this using either AdminClient or some API? Is it a costlier operation because this command takes 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: @Gibbs The CLI simply wraps Java (or Scala) code, so yes, you can

Comment: Could you help me with an java/python API page of it?

Comment: @Gibbs [You can search the source code for the class that is ran](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-configs.sh#L17). Or you can use Python [AdminClient](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.incremental_alter_configs)